# Electric field in vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields

A positive electric charge moves in vacuum and enters a region of space, where there is a uniform electric field, with a velocity perpendicular to the direction of the electric field. What would happen to the electric field?

Comment: you can easily find on the internet. I have also treated the topic in my instagram profile @aiuto.mateamtica.fisica

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the positive charge which enters the existing electric field (in whatever manner it be), distorts the field around it. This is because the charge itself has an electric field associated with it.

However, in regular calculations, we assume point charges which have no or negligible magnitudes of their own electric fields, and that have negligibly small effects on the external electric field. Thus, we can conveniently ignore the slight distortions in the external electric field around the positive charge, during relevant calculations.